# Eureka client on aws not able to connect to peer services (eureka clients)

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot, netflix-eureka, service-discovery

I am developing a microservice apps using spring, spring boot, eureka (for service discovery) and ribbon.

My application on consist of three services client, server and eureka-server

client and server both get registered with eureka-server and later client makes call to server using the eureka service discovery.

I am able to locally run the application and things works perfectly fine.

But when deploying on aws things go haywire.

Steps followed

- Three ec2 instance in same security group.
- Each microservice is running as docker container with properly exposed ports.
- One ec2 instance has elastic ip. Eureka-server container is running on it.
- Client and Server container are deployed on other two ec2 instances.

Result

**When using ECS**

- Client and server are able to register themselves with Eureka-server.

  ```
  Application AMIs    Availability Zones  Status
  HELLO-CLIENT    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 3fcd1c92386d:hello-client:8071
  HELLO-SERVER    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 6a5d643b32e1:hello-server:8072
  ```
- When hitting client endpoint getting java.net.UnknownHostException.

  ```
  Whitelabel Error Page

  This application has no explicit mapping for /error,so you are seeing
  this as a fallback.

  Sun Sep 10 08:38:17 GMT 2017
  There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
  I/O error on GET request for "http://hello-server/hello/server/":6a5d643b32e1; 
  nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: 
  6a5d643b32e1
  ```

**When using Docker Swarm**

- Client and server are able to register themselves with Eureka-server.

  ```
  Application AMIs    Availability Zones  Status
  HELLO-CLIENT    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - ip-10-255-0-5.ap-south-1.compute.internal:hello-client:8071
  HELLO-SERVER    n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - ip-10-255-0-6.ap-south-1.compute.internal:hello-server:8072
  ```
- When hitting client endpoint getting Connection timed out.

  Whitelabel Error Page

  ```
  This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing 
  this as a fallback.

  Sun Sep 10 11:22:20 GMT 2017
  There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
  I/O error on GET request for "http://hello-server/hello/server/": 
  Operation timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is 
  java.net.ConnectException: Operation timed out (Connection timed out)
  ```

**Eureka Configuration**

```
    application.properties
    --------
    spring.application.name=eureka-server
    server.port=8070

    bootstrap.yml
    --------
    eureka:
      client:
        registerWithEureka: false
        fetchRegistry: false
        server:
          waitTimeInMsWhenSyncEmpty: 0
        service-url:
          defaultZone: http://<Elastic IP of eureka server>:8070/eureka
```

**Server configuration**

```
    application.properties
    --------
    spring.application.name=hello-server
    server.port=8072

    bootstrap.yml
    --------
    eureka:
      client:
        service-url:
          defaultZone: http://<Elastic IP of eureka server>:8070/eureka
```

**Client configuration**

```
    application.properties
    --------
    spring.application.name=hello-client
    server.port=8071

    bootstrap.yml
    --------
    eureka:
      client:
        service-url:
          defaultZone: http://<Elastic IP of eureka server>:8070/eureka
```

**Rest Client configuration**

```
    Resource.java
    ---------------------------------
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("/hello/client")
    public String hello(){
            String uri = "http://hello-server/hello/server/";
            return restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);
    }


    Config.java
    ----------------------------
    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(){
    return  new RestTemplate();
    }
```

Comment: How do you register to eureka. Can you share your application.properties files. And how is your docker set up? Are you using docker-swarm or compose?

Comment: Hi Barbakini, I have added the configuration detail above.

Comment: And how is your `RestTemplate`configuration in client? Are you directly writing ip or docker container name or eureka registered name of server? most probably, your problem is in client service. I think client does not aski about server service to eureka and try to connect directly with a written name or ip address that cannot be resolved.

Comment: Are the dockers in the same network? if not you need to make both being in the same, otherwhise they can't see each other

Comment: @juanlumm obviously containers see each other because both server and client can register themselves to eureka.

Comment: Hi Barbakini, I have added the client configuration in the question.

Comment: It all looks like okay. I have no more guess, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to resolve this problem. Here the problem is system is trying to ping the Eureka client using the docker container id as host which system cannot resolve. In the microservice configuration set the `eureka.instance.preferIpAddress=true` for all the services. It will definitely solve the problem.